# AngularJS templates don't work with Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have developed a REST application using Spring in NetBeans IDE.
Here is the relevant dir structure:
[image: project structure]

I want to integrate Angular functionality into it, but will prefer to keep it as a single app, rather than separate Angular and Spring apps.

The main `index.html` file should show the template `home.html` on the front page.

**The Problem:**

Adding HTML files to the `templates` folder doesn't seem to work in the Angular application. If I try to access the `index.html` and `home.html` files through Angular, I get a 404 error, but I can open them directly.

Here's the controller in my Spring application for these two files:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

I have written AngularJS code before by itself, and I didn't have any problems.

- Am I mixing some things that I shouldn't?
- Do I create all my AngularJS code in a separate folder, away from `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Since you *can* access these files directly from the browser, open the browser's console - the network tab - and compare the request that Angular makes with the one that works.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot, or just spring-mvc? Why do you define controllers for static files?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos A couple of differences: The working request has the `Request URL` as `localhost:8080/home` and it does not have a `Referrer` in `Request Headers` section. Also the content length is much shorter(21 vs 306). I guess this is because the `home.html` file only has a couple of words of text. Also, there are two non-working requests made.

Comment: @JBNizet Spring Boot. The controller is a universal one for the whole thing. It contains all the `@RequestMapping`s for the REST back-end logic(around 30 of them). Do I not need the two `@RequestMapping`s I have shown here?

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content. Static resources should be under src/main/resources/static, not under src/main/resources/templates. Then you can access them directly, without any RequestMapping, using /index.html or /home.html.

Comment: @JBNizet I already have my CSS and JS files in the `static` folder. Don't static files only include non-changing data such as scripts and images?

Comment: How is a html file more "changing" that a JS, CSS or image file? They're all static resources that must be downloaded by the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103939/discussion-between-cst1992-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring maps your files placed in `src/main/resources/static` to the root directory of your application. This means a CSS file in your `src/main/resources/static/css/` folder can be accessed by simply using the `/css` relative path.

Static resources such as CSS, Javascript, templates or images should therefore be placed in the `static` folder, where Angular will be able to access it.

This restriction does not extend to your main `index.html` file, and you can place it in the main project directory or under `templates`.

Answer taken from JBNizet in comments.